# Cannot pass a #define integer as parameter of uint8_t / int type or as array index

Tags: c, embedded

Having a weird issue, basically I cannot use **#define** directive to declare an integer and then use that integer as a function parameter or to index an array.

The only way to get the following examples to work is to declare them as

```
const uint8_t LOC3 = 3;
```

and

```
const uint8_t PORTA = 0;
```

---

Here is the define:

```
#define LOC3 3;
```

Here is the function prototype:

```
void spi_Setup(USART_TypeDef *spi,
            uint8_t location, <-- this parameter here
            bool master,
            char* rxBuffer,
            char* txBuffer);
```

Even when declaring the parameter as **int** type, it will still not allow me to call the function like so:

```
spi_Setup(USART1, LOC3, true, receiveBuffer, transmitBuffer);
```

The same applies to array indexing:

```
#define PORTA 0;
```

Here is calling the struct:

```
GPIO->P[PORTA].DOUTCLR = 1 << 1;
```

As previously stated neither of these examples work,

---

Compiler settings:

Dialect: C99
Compiler: GNU ARM embedded toolchain

Compiler flags:

> -g -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -std=c99 '-DDEBUG=1' '-DEFM32ZG222F32=1' -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//platform/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/EFM32ZG_STK3200/config" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/common/bsp" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//platform/Device/SiliconLabs/EFM32ZG/Include" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/common/drivers" -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -mno-sched-prolog -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

Assembler flags:

> -g -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -c -x assembler-with-cpp -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//platform/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/EFM32ZG_STK3200/config" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/common/bsp" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//platform/Device/SiliconLabs/EFM32ZG/Include" -I"/home/access/Downloads/simplicitystudio/pkg/simplicitystudio/opt/simplicitystudio/developer/sdks/gecko_sdk_suite/v2.3//hardware/kit/common/drivers" '-DEFM32ZG222F32=1'

Linker flags:

> -g -gdwarf-2 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -T "${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker -Map="${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.map" --specs=nano.specs

I've asked my old man who is an old hand and he says this is rather weird. I agree as I have never had issues using #defines in this way, in fact it is considered convention.

---

I have tried to encircle the digit in a set of parentheses i.e.

```
#define LOC3 (3)
```

However that also does not work.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks in advance,
MM25

Comment: `#define LOC3 3;`. Remove the `;`.

Comment: `#define` does not declare something. It defines a **preprocessor** macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define LOC3 3;
```

You need to remove `;` otherwise your function call looks like

```
spi_Setup(USART1, 3; , true, receiveBuffer, transmitBuffer);
```

which is no valid C syntax.

```
#define LOC3 3
```

will work.